# Grails - ORM join to show name vs id

Tags: grails

Using scaffolding to develop a simple CRUD for accessing Resource.

I have a table with

```
ResourceType:
{ 
  Name
}
Example: Developer, Manager, Director
```

I have a table of

```
Resource:
{
  Name,
  ResourceType resourcetype
}
Example: Bob Jones of type Develper. Grace Smith of type Manager
```

I have the definition working to get the relationship to show the data on the web interface:
ResourceType:
Name, Resource_Id

The problem is that I am getting:

```
Bob Jones, 0
Grace Smith, 1
Alex Rodgers, 1
```

I want to have the view show the name from the ResourceType:

```
Bob Jones, Developer
Grace Smith, Manager
Alex Rodgers, Manager
```

Also, for new data entry, the drop down should list the names from ResourceType rather than the Ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding toString() method of `ResourceType` might help.

```
String toString() {
      Name
}
```